# Azure function access to storage account

Tags: c#, azure, function, storage, account

In my case, I want to access a storage account from Azure function app. Both are in the same subscription and resource group. I have modified the IAM policy to allow azure function to access the storage account. However, I am getting the following error:

Azure.RequestFailedException: Service request failed.
Status: 403 (This request is not authorized to perform this operation.)
ErrorCode: AuthorizationFailure

Headers:
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
x-ms-request-id: ***
x-ms-client-request-id: ***
x-ms-error-code: AuthorizationFailure
Date: Sun, 08 Aug 2021 19:21:00 GMT

at Azure.Storage.Blobs.BlobRestClient.GetPropertiesAsync(String snapshot, String versionId, Nullable`1 timeout, String leaseId, String encryptionKey, String encryptionKeySha256, Nullable`1 encryptionAlgorithm, Nullable`1 ifModifiedSince, Nullable`1 ifUnmodifiedSince, String ifMatch, String ifNoneMatch, String ifTags, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Azure.Storage.Blobs.Specialized.BlobBaseClient.GetPropertiesInternal(BlobRequestConditions conditions, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken, String operationName)

Comment: Are you running the function with its own identity? Do you have firewall rules enabled on the storage account?

Comment: @pinkfloydx33, this is what I have done:

Comment: Please edit your question and include what permissions you have allowed?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look on the [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-add-output-binding-storage-queue-vs-code?tabs=in-process&pivots=programming-language-csharp) on how we can connect to Storage with Azure functions

Also, we need to check few things as below:

1. Add AzureWebJobsStorage and storage connection strings in Configuration -> Application Settings.
2. Storage account > IAM > Add role assignment, and add the special permissions for this type of request:

- Storage Blob Data Contributor
- Storage Queue Data Contributor

3. Also, check for the Application Insights log steams for the errors and find you see anything related to CORS.